# customize autocomplete field in google map api

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps-api-3

I am new to google map api ,there is a form in my project & two fields with name city and address. I want to search the location within that address and city only. How can I achieve this?initially i take only one field i.e location.but bound is not restrict the search.
 html part:

```
div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6">
 <span>Location:</span>
<input type="text" id="search_txt" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter a location" />
```

js part:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {

  var cityBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
  new google.maps.LatLng(18.520430,73.856744)
 );

var options = {
  bounds: cityBounds,
  types: ['(cities)'],  componentRestrictions: { country: 'in' }

};
 var input = document.getElementById('search_txt');
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);



  });
```

Comment: Add the code--show us your attempts so far.

Comment: Show what have  you done so far.

Comment: thanks for quick reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete), in order to use autocomplete, you will need to load the Google Places library using the `libraries` parameter in the bootstrap URL for the Google Maps JavaScript API.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
```

Here is an [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform) from Google docs:

> This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
>   of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information. This
>   example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
>   parameter when you first load the API. For example:
>
> ```
> <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">
> ```

```
  var placeSearch, autocomplete;
  var componentForm = {
    street_number: 'short_name',
    route: 'long_name',
    locality: 'long_name',
    administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
    country: 'long_name',
    postal_code: 'short_name'
  };

  function initAutocomplete() {
    // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
    // location types.
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
        {types: ['geocode']});

    // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
    // fields in the form.
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
  }

  function fillInAddress() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    for (var component in componentForm) {
      document.getElementById(component).value = '';
      document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }
```

Check this related SO question: [Google Map Autocomplete Form Customization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28633273/google-map-autocomplete-form-customization)

Comment: i already use libraries=places in my google api.but i forgot to placed a code here.also use the place change in autocomplete. i dont want to show map in form ,it only show search field which restrict the specific city and show only city limited location.

Answer (score 1):

Show what have  you done so far.. Check this link also might help

[google map api page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform#try-it-yourself)

Also I have came across this while searching Check this out as well

> Change the bounds of an existing Autocomplete
>
> Call setBounds() to change the search area on an existing
>   Autocomplete.
>
> // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
>   // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
>   function geolocate() {   if (navigator.geolocation) {
>       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
>         var geolocation = {
>           lat: position.coords.latitude,
>           lng: position.coords.longitude
>         };
>         var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
>           center: geolocation,
>           radius: position.coords.accuracy
>         });
>         autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
>       });   } }